# How to resize EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am new to AWS please let me know the following questions.
1. How to resize EMR cluster? To improve the processing of data.
2.How AWS will call dynamically EMR resizing mechanism for new EMr cluster.

Any link suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On the console choose your cluster, go to cluster details page and click resize. You can also do this [using cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-resize.html#ResizingParameters). But before doing any of these, you might want to read about how [EMR clusters work](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-how-does-emr-work.html).  Understand Master node, core nodes and task nodes etc. You can increase/decrease number of task nodes at will but remember that you can not shrink the size of core node instance group. You can terminate the core node but you need to be aware of the fact that this might result in data loss.